How to display a prefix tree in the console?
I have a class like this:
public class TreeNode {
    public String nodeName;

    public List<TreeNode> clildren = new ArrayList<>();

    TreeNode(String[] splittedTemplate) {
        splittedTemplate[0] = splittedTemplate[0].replaceFirst("\\(", "");
        splittedTemplate[splittedTemplate.length-1] = splittedTemplate[splittedTemplate.length-1].replaceFirst("\\)", "");
        nodeName = splittedTemplate[0];
        splittedTemplate[splittedTemplate.length-1] = splittedTemplate[splittedTemplate.length-1];

        boolean subArrayStarted = false;
        int subArrayStartPosition = -1;
        int openBracketsCount = 0;
        int closeBracketCount = 0;

        String subArray = "";

        for(int i = 1; i < splittedTemplate.length; i++) {
            if(splittedTemplate[i].contains("(")) {
                subArrayStarted = true;
                if(subArrayStartPosition == -1) {
                    subArrayStartPosition = i;
                }
                openBracketsCount += Utils.getCountNumbersInStr('(', splittedTemplate[i]);
            }

            if(subArrayStarted) {
                if(subArrayStartPosition == i) {
                    subArray += splittedTemplate[i];
                } else {
                    subArray += "," + splittedTemplate[i];
                }
            } else {
                clildren.add(new TreeNode(new String[]{splittedTemplate[i]}));
            }

            if(splittedTemplate[i].contains(")")) {
                closeBracketCount += Utils.getCountNumbersInStr(')', splittedTemplate[i]);
                if(openBracketsCount == closeBracketCount) {
                    clildren.add(new TreeNode(subArray.split(",")));
                    subArrayStarted = false;
                    subArrayStartPosition = -1;
                    subArray = "";
                    closeBracketCount = 0;
                    openBracketsCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void toStringNode(int tabs) {

        String resultString = "";
        int stringLength = 0;


        for(TreeNode val: clildren) {
            stringLength += val.getStringLength();
        }

        stringLength -= nodeName.length();

        resultString += Utils.copySpace(stringLength/2) + nodeName + Utils.copySpace(stringLength/2);

        if(tabs == 1) {
            System.out.println(resultString);
        }
    }

    public int getStringLength() {
        if(this.clildren.size() == 0) {
            return this.nodeName.length()+2;
        }

        int stringLength = 0;

        for(TreeNode val: clildren) {
            stringLength += val.getStringLength();
        }

        return stringLength;
    }
}

In my program I split the string "(a,b,(c),d)" and get an array
String[] splitTemplate. The class constructor turns this array into a prefix tree. I'm stuck at the point of outputting this prefix tree to the console as a tree.
The toStringNode method should print the tree to the console.
I need to display the tree in this format:

I experimented with the code and it turned out to display the tree in this form:

For another tree (a, b, (c, d, (e, f), g, (1, 2, (3, 4))), 5):

But that's not what I need

Every time you recurse you indent, when you’re done you dedent.

@DaveNewton, at the beginning I had code like this. But it is not suitable for the final solution

So if you were laying it out by hand what would you need to do?

@DaveNewton, my idea is to traverse the tree recursively. With it, you can get a line for each level of the tree, and then simply print it to the console. But I haven’t figured out how to implement this yet
